# Ambari redirects to NiFi automatically

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hortonworks-dataflow

I installed NiFi in my Hortonworks and whenever I start my session in Ambari I'm redirected to NiFi. Has anyone any idea how to change it so that my localhost:8080 does not automatically redirect to NiFi? I attached the image below.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change the port that NiFi runs on since the default is 8080 which is also the port that Ambari runs on. The port is defined in nifi.properties with the property nifi.web.http.port=8080

Comment: Thank you very much Bryan! That is the solution :)